# How can I install The Sony camera remote SDK in Xcode to develop an app in SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, sdk, sony

So, I'm trying to install the Sony camera remote sdk into Xcode to develop an app in swiftui. I'm still in the learning process so I thought this would be a nice challenge to improve developing. Since there is not an easy package to install with the packet manager in Xcode and the files provided in the sdk are C headers files, I can't understand how to do it

I tried importing the sdk filter into the Xcode project but when I try to call a function of the sdk Xcode give me error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.